# How does copyright work on questionnaires with similar items?

Tags: copyright, survey-research

I have seen in certain types of questionnaires that the content is very similar, and that, possibly by coincidence, certain phrases are the same.

Let me give you an example: the organizational culture measurement questionnaires.

If one compares different questionnaires, you normally will find similarities in certain items and some may be exactly the same. This is not because a copy has been made, but because human resources has a general consensus on what things should be measured. For example, because everyone agrees that the leadership of the bosses should be measured, therefore we commonly find items such as:

*My boss is a good leader*

or with respect to the company:

*I feel happy in this company*

My question arises from this: Could an author who created a questionnaire claim copyright infringement by other questionnaires with similar or identical items, even if this happened by pure chance?

Comment: Depending on the purpose of the survey, I’d imagine many of them would be covered by Fair Use.

Answer (score 2):

I'm answering from my perspective as a health services researcher. I am not a lawyer. If you know that there are a number of proprietary copyrighted surveys in your field and you think you might run into issues with them, then you are arguably on the wrong Stack Exchange (maybe try the [Law Stack Exchange](https://www.rand.org/health-care/surveys_tools/mos/36-item-short-form/terms.html) site), and you may also need your own legal advice.

---

### Peer-reviewed literature vs. proprietary

First, is the survey proprietary or is it in the public domain? For example, the [RAND Short Form-36](https://www.rand.org/health-care/surveys_tools/mos/36-item-short-form/terms.html) (SF-36) survey was an early measure of health (specifically, we'd say health-related quality of life, or HRQoL). I think the original survey is in the public domain. I think that the researcher involved in its development later collaborated with Optum, a company owned by the US health insurer United Healthcare, to develop the proprietary SF-36v2. RAND is a non-profit corporation which explicitly licenses the RAND SF-36 for public use. For the SF-36v2, you have to pay to use it.

If you clearly copy question wording from a proprietary survey, then I imagine that there's a legal cause of action. If you copy wording without attribution from a survey published in peer-reviewed literature that isn't proprietary, then this seems to be plagiarism. The offended party would have to seek resolution with the publisher of the journal where the offending survey got published. I don't know what legal recourse you have if a for-profit firm buys the journal article and then reverse-engineers your survey.

Actually, my late mentors did have a US state take their survey and allow a for-profit survey firm to administer it and refine the items, but that was with their full knowledge and consent of all parties. That survey firm isn't raking in money from this - they are not rent seeking, in economics terms.

### Similar concepts being measured and similar question wording

Many times, different authors try to measure constructs, like physical function, depression symptoms, or cognitive impairment, that are well-established in the literature. For some constructs, there may be enough surveys that many or all of the questions you could use have already been used by some other researcher. Perhaps you should ask if you actually need to publish a new survey trying to measure the constructs - the answer may be yes, but you may be duplicating effort.

If you did your own work, funded by some government body or other generous donor, and you independently came up with similarly-worded questions as others have used, then it still seems to me that you are arguably in the clear. I would probably cite if my wording was very close to someone else's. Anyway, in evolution and engineering, and probably elsewhere, it's a known phenomenon that given similar goals, world conditions, or physical constraints, you can have people independently come up with similar solutions or animals evolve similarly.

Moreover, depending on what field you're in, you might have independently generated the questions from expert consensus or patient focus groups.

If I am a peer reviewer, and I realize that a lot of your content and/or questions overlap with an existing survey, I would want to assess if there's a good rationale to develop a new one. In health services research we often have established and widely used surveys for some concepts. If you tried to develop your own depression survey and your wording overlaps a lot with the PHQ-9 or the PROMIS depression scale, then I would be skeptical; the former is very widely used. If it's a less-commonly studied construct, then there's less likelihood of overlap, and the field should continue to refine ways to measure that construct.

In sum, it's not literally pure chance (I interpret this as randomness), but yes, there is a good chance that you might independently develop similar questions as another instrument if the field is well-studied.

---

I have a PhD in health services research, and my dissertation focused on some mathematical models used in measurement of psychosocial constructs. I have a fairly good knowledge of the field of psychosocial measurement. But as I mentioned, I am not a lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

Copyright law varies from place to place, so a valid answer might depend on where you are. But in general, it is a good idea to assume that copyright law applies to everything. Basically if you write something (or create in another medium) you own rights to it. Some places you may have to register the copyright as was true in the past in the US. Most places copyright is a matter of civil, not criminal, law. But I think there are exceptions.

There are some caveats, however. Copyright doesn't prevent you from using something, only from copying it or obtaining a copy illicitly. There are a few exceptions to the general prohibition against copying, but they are a bit subtle.

The first is [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use), but that is a subtle thing. While there are fair use exceptions for some uses, including research, they aren't unlimited exceptions and depend on a "proportional" standard that can only be adjudicated by agreement between parties or by a court in a lawsuit. (Note, this is a US view, things vary around the world).

So, since you are doing research, you can depend on fair use *up to a point*, but that point isn't very clear. A few items out of a hundred is probably not an issue. How few? No-one can say in general. If the copyright holder objects, then you have a problem that will be expensive to solve.

However, another caveat may be more important here. You can't really copyright things for which there is only one basic way to say or write. So lots of things in mathematics can't be copyrighted because the "expression" is more or less immutable. Copyright doesn't "protect" ideas, only the *expression* of ideas. So, if "The boss is kind and gentle" is the idea, then there are only a few ways that that can be said in a questionnaire, so it is unlikely anyone would have a basis for a copyright complaint.

Unless you copy a lot of those kinds of things from a single source. Then the source is more likely to start to question your intent and might want to raise it in a lawsuit. My guess is that is pretty unlikely, but don't discount it altogether. You can get a bad reputation as a researcher for things that don't break any legal rules.

But you also need to consider the question of plagiarism. If you copy a bit and don't cite the source then you have a different issue, though it, too, may be covered by the "one reasonable form of expression" idea.

A claim of copyright can always be made. Courts, however, won't be supportive of frivolous claims, where only a small part was copied or the reasonable ways to express an idea are very limited. Therefore it is unlikely that a claim is likely to be made if things happen "by chance". A valid claim would need to depend on fairly clear evidence, especially given the research (partial) exception as stated in the law.

See especially the section on the four considerations used to evaluate fair use claims in the link above. I think the third one is what you need to be most concerned with:

> the amount and substantiality of the portion used in relation to the copyrighted work as a whole;

But, of course, if you need to repeat a questionnaire in its entirety, say for reproducing the research, you can always ask the authors for permission.

Moreover, if you *reuse* a questionnaire that you find in a copyrighted work that you have valid access to, there should be no issue as long as you don't reproduce that questionnaire in your own work. You just refer to the published questionnaire in your methodology section.

Comment: As someone who teaches survey methods, I don’t think this analysis emphasizes the right things. It is best practice to use validated measures and to use identical wording that can be compared across surveys. I specifically discourage students from developing their own questions whenever possible. Citation is, of course, required.

Comment: @Dawn, you are then using the "only one way to express it" exception to copyright law. If it can't be validly said another way then it can't be copyrighted. It is an "idea" not an "expression". I don't think there is a conflict here.

Answer (score 0):

Answering from more of a scientific perspective... wording is everything in questionnaires.

The specific language is critically important, even if the general concept is the same. When you validate a survey or questionnaire-based scale, you are validating that specific language. Developing a copycat scale, or translating it to another language, removes the ability to compare to existing normative data and you lose all the benefits of past work towards validating the scale.

Therefore, I would think that most scales that are available for purchase or under a particular license would be most concerned with preserving the specific scale items: that's where the value is.